# InvalidOperationException when modifying XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to store some data in XML using ASP.NET. Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SkillsInformation>
  <Details id="1">
    <Name>XML</Name>
    <Description>Fundamentals of XML</Description>
  </Details>
  <Details id="2">
    <Name>Java</Name>
    <Description>Fundamentals of Java</Description>
  </Details>
</SkillsInformation>
```

I want to insert skills, but I get and error saying,

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code.
{"The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."}
```

Here is how I created the `Details` element and added the Attribute `id`.

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    //Get the nodes
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Details");
    //Counting nodes to get count of the skill items
    idCount = nodeList.Count;

    xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("skills.xml"));

    XmlElement parentElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Details");
    //xmlDoc.AppendChild(parentElement);

    String attributeValue = idCount++.ToString();
    XmlAttribute idAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("id", attributeValue);
    //idAttribute.Value = attributeValue;
    parentElement.Attributes.Append(idAttribute);


    XmlAttribute nameElement = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
    nameElement.InnerText = name.Text;

    XmlAttribute descriptionElement = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Description");
    descriptionElement.InnerText = description.Text;

    parentElement.AppendChild(nameElement);
    parentElement.AppendChild(descriptionElement);

    //xmlDoc.AppendChild(parentElement);

    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(parentElement);

    bindData();
```

Comment: Name and Description aren't attributes; attributes aren't child elements.

Comment: For future reference, it would have been helpful if you had told us on which line the exception was occurring.

Comment: And your node count is always zero as you are counting before you load the file...

Comment: This has a code smell and doesn't seem to be incrementing for any reason other than laziness: `idCount++.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML shown, `Name` and `Description` are [elements](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp), not [attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp).  To create that XML you need to do:

```
        var nameElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
        nameElement.InnerText = name;

        var descriptionElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Description");
        descriptionElement.InnerText = description;

        parentElement.AppendChild(nameElement);
        parentElement.AppendChild(descriptionElement);
```